# Page not redirecting in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am working on a jsp page where i want to redirect to pages according to following condition. only the else part is working even when i type Google in text field. P.S. I am hosting it on localhost Glassfish Server

```html
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
    String x = request.getParameter("browse");
    if (x == "Google" || x == "google") {
        response.sendRedirect("http://www.google.com");
    } else if (x == "youtube" || x == "Youtube" || x == "you tube" || x == "Music") {
        response.sendRedirect("http://www.youtube.com");
    }else {
        response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:11146/Project_Julie/" + x + ".jsp");
    }
%>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you thought about using the JSTL ? e.g. `<c:if test="${fn:toLowerCase(x) eq "google"}">` (BTW I removed the javascript tag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `equals()` method instead of `==` operator and your code will work.

replace `if(x=="Google" || x=="google")` with `if("google".equals(x.toLowerCase()))` apply same change in else if clause too.

Comment: and maybe even `x != null && "google".equals(x.toLowerCase())`

Comment: @DJDaveMark nice suggestion

Comment: Thanks a lot, It worked